# Generate Random String with Dependent Probability

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, random, probability

Using `JavaScript` or `jQuery`, I'm trying to create a `string` generator that relies on dependent `probability`.
For example, if I generated "doctor" on the first go, no other "doctors" would appear. It would go to another `url`, like "pimp". Once all `string` names have been used, it would generate a completely random one again, until the next 6 have no repeats, and so on.

For context, here's the `code` I have so far for independent probability (just random strings):

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  var urls = [
    "mafia",
    "doctor",
    "cupid",
    "mafioso",
    "pimp",
    "detective"
  ];

  var url = urls[Math.floor(Math.random() * urls.length)];
  $("#log").append(url + "<br>"); // append url to log
 
 var last = $("#log").split("<br>").pop(); // get last part
  var text = urls.replace(last, ""); // replace in the array, hopefully
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Generate</button><br>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Any thoughts, even a step to achieving dependent `probability`, is an answer I'd gladly accept. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the randomly chosen item from the array when picked, and if the array's length is 0, reset it to the original array:

```js
var origURLs = [
  "mafia",
  "doctor",
  "cupid",
  "mafioso",
  "pimp",
  "detective"
];
var currURLs;
$("button").click(function() {
  if (!currURLs || currURLs.length === 0) currURLs = [...origURLs];
  const randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currURLs.length);
  const url = currURLs.splice(randIndex, 1)[0];
  $("#log").append(url + "<br>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Generate</button><br>
<div id="log"></div>
```